# Filter in Google sheets gives me blank if I select the whole column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula that works pretty well.

```
=filter(RawData!A:A,RawData!F:F=D2)
```

If I drag the formula, it shows #N/A until the criteria returns a date. Example:

```
#N/A
#N/A
#N/A
2020-08-01
#N/A
#N/A
```

But I don't want to drag the cells, I want it to fill automatically, so I edited the last criteria like this:

```
=filter(RawData!A:A,RawData!F:F=D:D)
```

Without specifying the exact D column, it just gives me blank cells.

The strange thing is that I have a similar formula elsewhere and its working. Just different sheets but with the same kind of data.

Anyone knows what might be causing this?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oj7LSbsRF_7HDEgcXsJw4xpOFKHhLBm6is9EVfqTqzw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As ever, please share a link to your sheet or to a copy of your sheet, being sure to set the link sharing permission to "Anyone with the link can edit." We can only assess a problem if we can see all the pieces. Otherwise, it's like calling a mechanic and saying, "My car is making a weird noise. My other car isn't making a weird noise. What's wrong with the first car?" ... and then not letting the mechanic see the car.

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? It's all blank cells because no match is found (one match is found in the first example because the indexes are different - `D30` matched `RawData!F31`). Also, do you want the blank cells to be appended an the matches (the dates) to show up on the matching row, or the dates to show up on top?

Comment: It doesnt work because if you drag and drop instead, you find the right matches for example in row 30. But when you "D:D", its all blank cells.
Basically the idea is the same used in B2 Formula.
I just want to show dates if the criteria matches. It works normally with B2 formula and also if I drag and drop using "B2" "B3" etc... It just doesnt work if I use D:D (but it works in the B2 formula)

Comment: I posted an answer, can you please take a look at it? Since I'm not sure what exactly you want to accomplish, I just provided an explanation for this method not working. In case you clarify what you want to accomplish (**do you want to find matches for the same row or for any row?**), I'd consider updating my answer with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
=filter(RawData!A:A,RawData!F:F=D2)
```

You are looking for any cell in `RawData!F:F` that matches `D2`; it's not required that this cell is on the same row. If, for example, `RawData!F15` matches `D2`, `RawData!A15` will be returned.

That is a far less restrictive filter than the one corresponding to:

```
=filter(RawData!A:A,RawData!F:F=D:D)
```

In this last case, the match should be found in a specific row. For example, `RawData!F15` matching `D2` will not cause `RawData!A15` to be returned. Instead, `F2` will be compared to `D2`, `F3` to `D3`, and so on. And with your current data, there is no match to be found.

That's the reason the same formula "works" on `B` and not on `C` (there are matches to be found for `=filter('Lead + source'!H:H,'Lead + source'!A:A=D:D)`, but not for `=filter(RawData!A:A,RawData!F:F=D:D)`).